# Textbox.text binding to MySettings is not working

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm working on a WinForm application of VB.NET 4.0

I bind a MySetting property to a TextBox it runs ok until I change the value in the TextBox; the program keep reading the old value even if I do a reload before read.

I remember that is not need to update save or reload, because I made another WinForm application and the value is update without the need of add any code by me.

When the value is updated in MySetting after I change the value in the TextBox? When the TextBox lost focus?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Or show a bit of code/screenshot of what's going on?

Comment: If I select a TextBox, in design time, In the property panel I have a property called ApplicationSetting --> PropertyBinding. So I Bind the Text property to a MySetting variable. After that. the whole idea is if I change the text value, now in running time, the value is save in the application settings automatically without any code. But that is not working  because the application keeps seeing the old value. So I don't know why don't work as expected.

Comment: Hmm, that begs the question where "old value" came from.  Apparently it did used to work once.  My crystal ball says that you did something that prevents the app from shutting down normally.  Like using Environment.Exit() or the VB.NET `End` keyword or hiding exceptions.

Comment: No, I'm trying to use the value in MySettings without closing the program. So I presume that the values are only saved at application exit and not during running time.

Comment: If this helped resolve the issue, please upvote it.  If the question is answered, please click the checkmark so it moves off the UnAnswered list.

Answer (score 1):

My.settings.Save()

This saves any settings that you have set.
For instance.

```
My.Settings.txbVal = txbName.text
My.Settings.Save()
```

Comment: in c# it's `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using VB.NET. I know what you are talking about, but I do it before without any code. Please read my answer to  Sastreen up here.

Comment: I believe the binding just sets the source of the data, and won't automatically update (and save) the value unless you call the save function.  I will say that I am not 100% sure of this, but I would add an event handler on changed text or another event to call the save method just to test it.  You may not have to set the value, just call the save method.

Comment: Check Plutonix post above... he's right about User scope vs Application scope settings.

Answer (score 1):

*`I have a property called ApplicationSetting --> PropertyBinding. So I Bind the Text property to a MySetting variable.`*

`Application` scoped Settings are ReadOnly, so VB is not going to update the value in Settings from the control and as a result they are never updated.  You can see how they are handled in the designer code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property AppFoo() As String
    Get
        Return CType(Me("AppFoo"), String)
    End Get
End Property
```

Compare to a `User` scoped setting:

```
Public Property UserFoo() As String
    Get
        Return CType(Me("UserFoo"), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me("UserFoo") = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Change the setting to with User scope so it can be updated.  To bind to a User Setting takes but one line of code, and will allow the VB App Framework to update and save automatically.

```
' in form load:
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", My.Settings, "UserFoo")
```

Bound this way, changes to the textbox will update the related value in `My.Settings` and the VB App Framework will save them when the app exits normally.

Comment: Yep... Forgot about that too.  You absolutely must use user scope if you are changing the values at runtime.

Comment: In case you don't know, you can change the scope of the setting by clicking the dropDown box in the "Scope" column of your particular setting in the project properties "setting" menu.